# Phase diagram for 1,3 butadiene + acetonitrile binary mixture

Tags: thermodynamics

Acetonitrile (82 deg C b.p) is used to absorb 1,3 butadiene (-4.4 deg C b.p) in several manufacturing processes.  I am looking for a binary phase diagram at 1 atm.  The only thing I could find was this: http://www.ddbst.com/en/EED/VLE/Images/VLE%20Acetonitrile;1,3-Butadiene_001.png .  This figure is for a particular temperature and varying pressures.  I am looking for a similar diagram at 1 atm, with temperature on the Y-axis and mole fraction of butadiene on the X-axis.  Here is an example for water-ethanol: [image]  Can someone help?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like more of a Chemistry question

Comment: This is definitely a chemical engineering question.  This process is used to make 1,3 butadiene in a fractionator in the city where I live.

Comment: That may be, but nevertheless you may have more luck on Chemistry Stack Exchange with the expertise there